# Measuring time for my array of random numbers to print is always showing 0 seconds

Tags: c++, time, clock, time.h

Just wondering why my stopwatch is always showing 0 seconds or 0 milliseconds no matter the amount of random numbers in my array.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double clock_start()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    return start;
}

void random_number()
{
    int array[10000];
    srand(6);
    cout << "10k Random numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 99 + 1;
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    //-------------------------//

    random_number();
    clock_t elapsed = (clock() - clock_start()) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
    cout << "Stopwatch: " << elapsed << "ms" << " or " << elapsed * 1000 << "s" << endl;

    //-------------------------//
    system("pause > nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `clock()` and `clock_start()` in the same expression. They will execute at nearly the same time. `clock_start()` just returns `clock()`. `clock() - clock()` will definitively be very small...

Comment: `clock()` would return the same value as `clock_start` (or, at the very least, very close to it), due to the fact, that they are invoked one after another.

Comment: In c++, operand evaluation order is not specified. It's possible for your example to measure a negative time span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(clock() - clock_start())` will be evaluated in the blink of an eye.

All `clock_start()` does is return `clock()`. (In fact, a good optimising compiler will replace `clock_start()` with `clock()` !)

The difference will almost certainly be zero. Did you want something like

```
clock_t start = clock();
random_number();
clock_t elapsed = (clock() - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
```

instead?

Comment: Yes it worked actually!
So what i did was deleting the clock_start() function.
and added:

    clock_t start = clock();

to my main function.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the clock_start() function and I added the:

```
clock_t start = clock();
```

to my main function.